# How to parse asterisk in json file as string via jq

Tags: json, bash, shell, sh, jq

Here is a json file named test.json for testing

```
{
    "name": "Google",
    "location": {
        "street": "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway",
        "city": "Mountain View",
        "state": "California",
        "country": "US"
    },
    "employees": [
        {
            "name": "Michael",
            "division": "Engineering"
        },
        {
            "name": "Laura",
            "division": "HR"
        },
        {
            "name": "Elise",
            "division": "Marketing * test"
        }
    ]
}
```

if I use the `jq` code to parser it like below:

```
cat test.json | jq -r '.employees[2].division'
```

it will work well and give a correct result:

```
Marketing * test
```

but I use `$()`, the bad thing will happen!

```
echo $(cat test.json | jq -r '.employees[2].division')
```

the result will list all file names under current folder! like:

```
my1.json my2.json test.json test ...
```

I guess it `$()` run asterisk `*` as a shell script, but a string.

so how to make asterisk (`*`) in json file just as a string when I am using `jq` ?. I am using Google cloud platform and Ubuntu 17.10

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Always use double-quotes around command-substitution to avoid `*` to be treated literally.  The `*` is a special character in shell that is a wildcard entry that expands to all the files available in the current working directory. You need to quote it to deprive of its special meaning (Refer [GNU bash man page](https://linux.die.net/man/1/bash) under Parameters section).

Also `jq` can process the file directly, you can avoid useless `cat` usage.

```
result="$(jq -r '.employees[2].division' < test.json)"
echo "$result"
```

should produce the result as expected.